# MBProgressHUD seems to be taking over my project

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

I have downloaded and copied the MBProgressHUD.h and MBProgressHUD.m into my project. Now when I run my project it forces my app icon the MBProgressHUD icon and now I have a navbar popping up with the label MBProgressHUD label showing up?

I haven't even implemented the HUD yet. It does this just by using

```
#import "MBProgressHUD"
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied in the images folder and it had all the icon and default images that set all these.

Comment: Just copy `MBProgressHUD.h` and `MBProgressHUD.m`. That's enough to use :)